# Cannot connect to my couchbase cluster with python SDK

Tags: python, couchbase

I can reach my couchbase cluster with a simple cURL:

```
curl -u $CB_USERNAME:$CB_PASSWORD  http://$CB_HOST/pools/default/buckets
```

but I do not manage to connect using the Python SDK:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from couchbase.auth import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.options import ClusterOptions
import os

# Configuration
CB_HOST = os.environ.get('CB_HOST')
CB_BUCKET = os.environ.get('CB_BUCKET')
CB_USERNAME = os.environ.get('CB_USERNAME')
CB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('CB_PASSWORD')

# Initialize Couchbase connection
auth = PasswordAuthenticator(CB_USERNAME, CB_PASSWORD)
options = ClusterOptions(auth)
cluster = Cluster(f'couchbase://{CB_HOST}', options)
```

This gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luc/code/couchbase/examples/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    cluster = Cluster(f'couchbase://{CB_HOST}', options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/luc/code/couchbase/examples/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 99, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/luc/code/couchbase/examples/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/couchbase/logic/wrappers.py", line 98, in wrapped_fn
    raise e
  File "/Users/luc/code/couchbase/examples/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/couchbase/logic/wrappers.py", line 82, in wrapped_fn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/luc/code/couchbase/examples/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 105, in _connect
    raise ErrorMapper.build_exception(ret)
couchbase.exceptions.UnAmbiguousTimeoutException: UnAmbiguousTimeoutException(<ec=14, category=couchbase.common, message=unambiguous_timeout (14), C Source=/Users/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/python/sdk/python-packaging-pipeline/py-client/src/connection.cxx:199>)
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you check the debug logs? You can do it by 

```export PYCBC_LOG_LEVEL=debug && python main.py```

Reference: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/howtos/collecting-information-and-logging.html#environmental-settings

Comment: The other thing you can try is to ensure that the connection is established by waiting for a few seconds.
```cluster.wait_until_ready(timedelta(seconds=5))```

Comment: Another thing to try, just to eliminate possible network/connectivity issues is to run SDK Doctor - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html

Comment: @MatthewGroves thanks I used sdk doctor and understand I was missing a couple of ports :) Can you make this an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to eliminate possible network/connectivity issues, I suggest [running SDK Doctor](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html).

From the docs:

> SDK doctor is a tool to diagnose application-server-side connectivity
> issues with your Couchbase Cluster. It makes the same connections to
> the Couchbase Server cluster that Couchbase SDKs make during
> bootstrapping, and then reports on the state of the connections
> made — giving diagnostic information that can help to solve puzzling
> network issues.

Hopefully that will help you identify any issues.